# GoogleMap snapshot doesn't show in BigPictureStyle Notification

Tags: android, bitmap, android-notifications

So I've been spending couple of days trying to get a Google Map snapshot show up in a notification. 
I have come as far as having a working bitmap in my MyGcmListener class (It's viewable from Android Studio when i click the View Bitmap link in the debugger). Now I'm trying to make it appear as a BigPictureStyle notification bitmap, but my luck strikes out. Here is the code:

```
           NotificationCompat.Builder note = new NotificationCompat
                    .Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(content);

            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style 
               = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();

            style.bigPicture(mapBit);

            note.setStyle(style);
            note.setAutoCancel(true);
            note.build();

            note.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(100,note.build());
```

This will result in a ordinary notification without any bitmaps attached.

Where do I go wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 min refining my search this is the answer:

```
note.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```